# Arabic store price format replace , with . magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, arabic

How can I change the format of the price in the frontend for the Arabic store?

Eg:د.إ.‏ 1٬486٫00 to د.إ.‏ 1٬486.00

instead of, I need to change with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the Eg:د.إ.‏ 1٬486٫00 to د.إ.‏ 1٬486.00

Open the file lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar.xml and search by RLM and replace , with .

```
<numbers>
    <defaultNumberingSystem>arab</defaultNumberingSystem>
    <otherNumberingSystems>
        <native>arab</native>
    </otherNumberingSystems>
    <symbols numberSystem="arab">
        **<decimal>.</decimal>**
        <group>٬</group>
        <list>؛</list>
        <percentSign>٪</percentSign>
        <plusSign>‏+</plusSign> <!-- includes RLM before sign -->
        <minusSign>‏-</minusSign> <!-- includes RLM before sign (002D) -->
        <exponential>اس</exponential>
        <superscriptingExponent draft="contributed">×</superscriptingExponent>
        <perMille>؉</perMille>
        <infinity>∞</infinity>
        <nan>ليس رقم</nan>
    </symbols>
```

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate to edit this file:

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ar.xml
```

Zend Locale definition are defined base on an international standard: perhaps evaluate if this is really necessary.

More information: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/